# Wingpanel Error

Tags: wingpanel

There is a strange wingpanel behaviour. When I want to select an option above in any application I can't. [image] 
Options disappear!! [image] and I don't know how to solve it. Please I need help.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some globalmenu indicator installed. This is not officially supported and can lead to issues which you seem to have.